# Add object to array from constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm currently working on a platform game which will have a lot of different blocks that will serve as walls and platforms. In order to know if a player has arrived att a point where there's an obstacle, I'd like to loop through an array of all blocks.

I could of course just add the objects to the array after I've created them:

```
    var blockArray = [];
    var block1 = new Block();
    blockArray.push(block1);
```

But lets face it, I'm lazy and the code becomes a bit cluttered. Is there some way to add the object to the array from inside the constructor, something like this:

```
    var blockArray = [];        
    function Block () {
          blockArray.push(this.Block);
    }
```

*where this.Block means the newly created object.*

Is there any way to reference an object like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The constructor really should not do that. Write a `function addNewBlock() { blockArray.push(new Block); }` that puts the new instance on that global array.

Comment: Be careful with the "this" keyword, in this case, the "this" is implicit which is the most common.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to reference an object like this?

Yes, it's literally `this`.

```js
var blockArray = [];

function Block() {
  this.foo = 42;
  blockArray.push(this);
}

new Block();

console.log(blockArray);
```